# Make ul behave like select list

Tags: jquery

I have an un ordered list which has a tree structure. What I am trying to achieve is that user see a select list. And only the level one items are shown to the user.

Then if the user clicks on one item and that item has child then show the absolute child of that item and so on.

```
$("#dropDownMenu #tree  li").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass('hide');
});

$("#dropDownMenu #tree > li").each(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hide');
});

        <div id="dropDownMenu">
        <div>
            <button id="clickMe">Click here</button>
        </div>
        <ul id="tree" class="tree no-bullet" style="display:none">
            <li>
                Animals
                <ul>
                    <li>Birds</li>
                    <li>
                        Mammals
                        <ul>
                            <li>Elephant</li>
                            <li>Mouse</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Animals1

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Is there any nice way to do that given that I would have variable number of levels?

Comment: you want something like this http://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd

Comment: there are some js plugins that does the same.

Comment: @WisdmLabs thanks I will look into it.

Comment: @WisdmLabs the issue with this example is that it is more towards menus I am looking for something more like drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

For the above structure, we can use the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#clickMe").on("click", function(){
        $("#tree").show();
    });
    $("li").on("click", function(){
        if($(this).children("ul")){
            $(this).children("ul").show();
        }
    });
});
```